# Can't connect to network share (SMB) with finder (but it works with terminal)

Tags: finder, network

For years, i've connected to our (windows) server with

1. finder -> go to -> connect with server
2. entering "smb://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Sharename" and hitting enter
3. username and password prompt opens, i enter them and confirm
4. network share shows up in finder as drive icon, done.

Since a week or so, this does not work anymore, there is no password prompt but an endless "connecting" animation (waited for minutes to test).

- Changing to CIFS or AFP makes no difference.
- Using the server network name instead of the IP address makes no difference.
- Not specifying a /share but let the server list its shares makes no difference.

Hints:

- I can ping the server with IP or network name
- i can connect to OTHER servers (NAS) in the network with SMB and AFP and CIFS
- Other imacs with Big Sur in the same network CAN conntect to the server.
- i CAN connect to the server with terminal command:
  mount_smbfs //user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Sharename ./Volumes/Sharename
  -> the password is promted -> the share drive icon appears in finder and i can access it

So it's just not working with the finder "go to" anymore, and i wonder why.

No major updates, i've been on Big Sur (11.5.2 (20G95)) for a while now, and the windows server has not updated either to new versions.

Any idea?

Comment: Hahaha I had the exact same issue arise. I'm guessing it will go away eventually after enough restarts of Finder/computer? In the meantime the terminal mount command works well (as long as you use your user's Desktop/ folder, mount will erase any permissions/ownerships you have on folders in /Volumes/), so `mkdir ~/Desktop/Share` then `mount -t smbfs smb://user@server/share ~/Desktop/Share`